# Как создать и стилизовать ветку обсуждения в комментариях?

Tags: html, wordpress, вёрстка

Имеется стиль родительского комментария, этот див отвечает за весь блок с дочерними. Подскажите пожалуйста как прикрепить вот этот список стилей к одному?

```
.depth-1 {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-bottom.gif") left bottom repeat-x;}
.depth-1 {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-top.gif") 0 5px repeat-x;}
.depth-1 {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-right.gif") 100% 0px repeat-y;}
.depth-1 {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-left.gif") 0 0 repeat-y;}
.depth-1 {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-br.jpg") right bottom no-repeat;}
.depth-1 {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-bl.jpg") left bottom no-repeat;}
.depth-1 {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-tr.jpg") right top no-repeat;}
.depth-1 {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-tl.jpg") left top no-repeat; width:100%;}
```

Или как редактировать полностью комменты, как закрыть дивы не после цикла каждого комментария, а после ответов на него... вот здесь наглядный пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть где-то статья, или можете помочь, очень прошу дайте ответ.

вот код этой верстки:

```
 #comments {}
#comments a {}
#comments h4 {padding-left:20px;}
.nocomments {padding: 0 20px 30px 20px;}
.message-bottom {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-bottom.gif")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-bottom.gif*/ left bottom repeat-x;}
.message-top {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-top.gif")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-top.gif*/ 0 5px repeat-x;}
.message-right {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-right.gif")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-right.gif*/ 100% 0px repeat-y;}
.message-left {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-left.gif")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-left.gif*/ 0 0 repeat-y;}
.mes-br {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-br.jpg")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-br.jpg*/ right bottom no-repeat;}
.mes-bl {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-bl.jpg")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-bl.jpg*/ left bottom no-repeat;}
.mes-tr {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-tr.jpg")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-tr.jpg*/ right top no-repeat;}
.mes-tl {position:relative; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-tl.jpg")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-tl.jpg*/ left top no-repeat; width:100%;}
    .message-by {padding:15px 0 5px 0; font:16px/18px "Trebushet MS"; color:#602600; text-align:center;}
    .message-count {text-align:center;}
    .message-count span {display:inline-block; border:1px solid #8a5f3b; font:12px/14px Georgia; position:relative; padding:0 5px;}
    .message-count span b.count-l {position:absolute; left:-74px; top:1px; height:14px; width:72px; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-number-right.gif")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-number-right.gif*/ left top no-repeat;}
    .message-count span b.count-r {position:absolute; right:-76px; top:1px; height:14px; width:74px; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-number-left.gif")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-number-left.gif*/ right top no-repeat;}
    .message-entry {position:relative; padding:10px 20px 20px 20px;}
        .message-time {font-size:11px; line-height:20px; color:#efe7c6; height:20px; width:250px; background: #b27110 url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-time-right.gif")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-time-right.gif*/ right top no-repeat; margin:10px 20px 10px 180px;}  
        .message-time span {display:block; height:20px; padding:0 25px; background: url("http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-time-left.gif")/*tpa=http://test2.ru/wp-content/themes/new/images/message-time-left.gif*/ left top no-repeat;}
```

вот как должно выводится:

```
<div id="comments" class="post">
                    <h4>кол-во комментариев </h4>

                      <div id="comment-2620" class="alt message-bottom"><div class="message-top"><div class="message-right"><div class="message-left">
                        <div class="mes-br"><div class="mes-bl"><div class="mes-tr"><div class="mes-tl">
                            <div class="message-by">Автор</div>
                            <div class="message-count"><span><b class="count-l">&nbsp;</b><a href="#comment-2620">1</a><b class="count-r">&nbsp;</b></span></div>
                            <div class="message-entry">

                                <p>Комментарий 1</p>
<p class="thdrpy">[Ответить]</p><div class="comment-childs chalt" id="comment-2621"><img alt='' src='аватарка' class='avatar avatar-32 photo' height='32' width='32' /><p><cite>-</cite> Reply:<br /><small class="commentmetadata">Время</small></p><p>Первый  ответ на комментарий<br />
</p>
<p class="thdrpy">[Ответить]</p><div class="comment-childs" id="comment-2623"><img alt='' src='Аватарка' class='avatar avatar-32 photo' height='32' width='32' /><p><cite>Роман</cite> Reply:<br /><small class="commentmetadata">Время</small></p><p>Ответ на первый ответ</p>
<p class="thdrpy">[Ответить]</p><div class="comment-childs chalt" id="comment-2624"><img alt='' src='Аватар' class='avatar avatar-32 photo' height='32' width='32' /><p><cite>-</cite> Reply:<br /><small class="commentmetadata">Время</small></p><p>Ответ на второй ответ</p>
</div></div></div>
                                <div class="message-time"><span>время</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div></div></div></div>
                    </div></div></div></div>     </div>
```

Comment: Покажите вашу верстку текущую

Comment: Я добавил как должно быть ) мучаясь 3 дня , сделал ерунду какую то без этих стилей( а хотелось бы научится как верстать именно таким образом

Answer (score 1):

Если не менять вашу верстку, достаточно добавить следующие стили:

```
.message-entry,
.comment-childs {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.comment-childs {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Так у родителя и потомков появится граница, а у потомков еще и отступ, как на картинке.

Comment: Спасибо большое)) но у меня стандартный вывод , я не могу привязать все эти дивы , я не могу понять куда их ставить в цикл вывода комментарий, это скрин и код как должно получится...  у меня получается какое то убожество , или каждый комментарий в отдельном таком окошке

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что вы привели пример верстки, которую хотите, но не знаете как получить и проблема заключается в выводе подобной верстки средствами WordPress?

Comment: Правильно поняли , если я ставлю вот этот код `<div id="comment-2620" class="alt message-bottom"><div class="message-top"><div class="message-right"><div class="message-left">
                        <div class="mes-br"><div class="mes-bl"><div class="mes-tr"><div class="mes-tl">`  на цикл комментарий , у меня получается каждый комментарий в таком классе, и ответы тоже в таком же классе, проблема в том что я не понимаю как сделать что б в одном блоке отображались и комментарии и ответы.

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста , хоть намекните каким образом это сделать можно?

Comment: У меня еще не было времени поставить вордпресс и разобраться с вашим вопросом

Comment: Спасибо , буду ждать .

Comment: Я надеюсь у вас когда нибудь найдется время(((